# Where can you find the protoplasm blobs in the mines?

Tags: vessel

In [Vessel](http://www.strangeloopgames.com/), where can you find the protoplasm blobs in the mines?

I'm able to get the three easy ones, but I am missing two. Here are the three I already have:

1. one during the not-so-spelunky descent,
2. one accessible with a ladder in the dark near two open tips and a lever,
3. one as an award for making the two fluros afraid of light push a lever in the ceiling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a video that includes all the protoplasm blobs

So you dont have to watch the whole video here are the times of each protoplasm:

1. 1:00 ~ 1:30;
2. 4:52;
3. 15:50;
4. 28:10;
5. 34:17;

Other videos from this series include all protoplasm blobs in the game

I think its hard to explain this question so its best to watch the video

Comment: The video is too long. I just miss two out of five.

Comment: But I still gave you +1 for finding the video.